# HTML Animated Cursors

Tags: html, css

I have tried animating cursors with .ani cursor files but none of them would load properly on Chrome or Firefox. It would always default back to the normal blue circle. Any .cur (non-animated) files would work properly.

Am I missing something?

```css
.q {
cursor:url(images/minigreen/ayes/wait.ani), wait
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<span class="q">wait</span><br>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply, `.ani` is not supported, emphasis, mine:

> All image formats supported by Gecko can be used. This means that you
>   can use PNG, GIF, JPG, BMP, CUR, etc. images. **ANI is not supported. An
>   animated PNG or GIF will not create an animated cursor**.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property#Limitations)

Comment: Ah... is it supported on chrome?