# My CSS cursor's style can't work in URL('.ani')

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cursor

I use the cursor style in .css file in `style` and using inline style, but it doesn't work.

This is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./../css/index.css"> -->
</head>

<body style="cursor: url('./../images/AppStarting.ani');">
  <!-- 一个术语的解释: -->
  <div>
    <dl>
      <dt>luoyang</dt>
      <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro harum facilis placeat quis, assumenda autem ad adipisci quasi dicta sint eaque veritatis omnis incidunt sequi non doloribus vero, maxime consequuntur.</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I found the `.ani` on another cursor website. Actually, I use lots of pics, but it still doesn't work and the inspector said:

[image]

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Animated Cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574287/html-animated-cursors)

Comment: Ani image not supported. Source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property#limitations

Comment: I have found the question after i asked the question . but jpg,png,and .cur are not used in my brower . And the question is the same.Maybe you can try it out use a pic that can works ,and if you dont mind ,you can send me that pic so I can try it again

Comment: I tried png it was not working but i tried this .cur image from w3school it is working
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=url(smiley.gif),url(myBall.cur),auto
my code is: cursor: url(myBall.cur), auto;

Comment: I download the pic  and trid it ,but  .... the question is still there .I tested all the browers and all no works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animated images like `.ani, .cur` file formats are not supported anymore [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property#limitations).

I found that the following points are must be met when you link your image.

1. Image should be in the same folder as your .html file
2. Image should be less than or equal 32x32 pixels
3. You must enclosed your CSS in `<style></style>` tags or use separate CSS style file
4. You must have any content within your  tag if not the CSS will not trigger.
5. `URL(...)` [must be](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property#syntax) followed by one of the fallback [keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#values) defined in the CSS specification, such as `auto` or `pointer`

I tried `.png, .jpg` files it is working by following those points. Your CSS looks fine therefor I assume your images are larger than 32x32 pixel. Reduce the image pixel to 32x32 and check. Hope its helps you.

**[LIMITATIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property#limitations)**

> In Gecko (Firefox) the limit of the cursor size is 128×128px. Larger cursor images are ignored. However, you should limit yourself to the size 32×32 for maximum compatibility with operating systems and platforms.
> (Due to a bug in Gecko 1.9.2-1.9.2.6, Firefox 3.6-3.6.6 on Windows limits to 32×32px. This is fixed in later versions.)

**UPDATE**
Working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: powderblue;
      cursor: url(cursor.png), auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <dl>
      <dt>luoyang</dt>
      <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro harum facilis placeat quis, assumenda autem ad
        adipisci quasi dicta sint eaque veritatis omnis incidunt sequi non doloribus vero, maxime consequuntur.</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But In chrome,I use the 16*16  and 32*32 pic to try it again ,It  still cant work.(I fill the html and the png pic in one folder as you say and I utilize my classmate'computer  to try ,it's still ineffective.) I dont know what is wrong,the console says "invalid property value".

Comment: @user16838235 did you try your CSS code inside separate CSS stylesheet file or inside head tag? please do not use styles in body tag directly you must close style tag. it wont work if you use it directly in html body tag. I have updated my answer

Comment: Yeah,I tried it once ,but no works.Can you send me you code ? I want to try your code in my computer ,to prove that if there's wrong in my code .Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to mention fallback keyword to URL, like auto or pointer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property#syntax

Comment: Ah,This problem has confused me two days ,I know why my code is wrong ,you answer is right.Thanks for your help!

Comment: please accept the answer if it is solved your problem, it might help others to find easily